# onActivityResult not working on fragments

Tags: onactivityresult

onActivityResult not working with fragments..how to call onActivityResult in a class which extends fragment not fragment activity.Is there any other method similar to onActivityResult in fragments?

Comment: Please post your code, what have you tried, what errors you get etc...

Comment: camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    //((ApplicationClass)getActivity().getApplication()).setFlagforCameraExpense(true);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
      android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

   }
  });

Comment: @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  switch (requestCode) {
  case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST:
   if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
    try {
     //save the image in an imageview
    } catch (Exception e) {
     return;
    }

   }
   break;
  }

  

 }

Comment: when iam calling onactivtyresult frm fragment activity its working fine but i want to call this method frm my framnet class..is it possible to do so?

Comment: There is issue in support library. Check this post: http://shomeser.blogspot.com/2014/01/nested-fragments-for-result.html

Answer (score 0):

1.
Make sure your code like this:

```
startActivityForResult(intent,req);
```

and not this:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,req);
```

2.
Make sure implement your Fragment's onActivityResult:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```